# Best way to automatically detect private variables in cached .net classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, resharper

Using private variables in cached .net classes is a recipe for strange and often hard to debug problems.

See for instance: http://code-smart.org.uk/information/beware-asp-net-mvc-actionfilterattributes-are-cached-between-requests/

This can leed to session mixups/swapping! Usually these problems are blamed on not setting the output cache correctly.

Can (should?) Resharper detect these problems? Or is there another way?

Comment: So you need to know when a class descended from `Attribute` has instance variables? My first guess would be yes, R# Structural Find and Replace could definitely find such things.

Comment: No, I would like to get a warning whenever I use a private variable in a class which will be cached once deployed.

Comment: Is there some algorithmic way of telling your tool which classes will be cached? If not, you're just going to have to check each class that you know about, right?

Comment: @AakashM I would like to take the human factor out of it. In large scale/team or legacy projects who knows if all developers thought about this. Also note that this kind of bug is practically undetectable (even once deployed)

Comment: If you had to do it manually, how would you determine if an instance of a class was cached?

Comment: To do it correctly, you'd need cross procedural data flow analysis for this. That's (very) difficult to do, and you'd likely not succeed for your first try. You can have a look at an open source (in-method) data flow engine implementaion at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/tree/master/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/SymbolicExecution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something [nDepend](https://www.ndepend.com/) might be able to do, it has a feature to be pretty much write linq to analyse code.

Here's some details about CLinq: https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html

It can be also used as part of your gated build pipeline:
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-console

Comment: I wrote a very brief intro to nDepend a while back: http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2014/05/ndepend-code-analysis-super-tool.html but I'd go to main site, but to get a full taste of the features check out the main site.

Comment: How come the -1, is nDepend not feasible for this or looking for a more detailed answer?